# regex error in XSL

Tags: xslt

Regex should verify such words a23-abcefghijk

```
<xsl:variable name="myRegex">
    <xsl:value-of select="a\\d{2}\\-[a-zA-Z]+" />
  </xsl:variable>
```

but I am getting syntax error I tried escape characters but didnt find any solution yet

Comment: do you try single quotes and with slashes? (<xsl:value-of select="/a\d{2}\-[a-zA-Z]+/" />)

Comment: I think you are using double-backslashes because of a habit learnt with other host languages. In C or Java, a backslash in a string literal needs to be escaped as "\\". That's not the case in XML or XSLT, where backslash has no special meaning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of your variable needs to be a string, so you need to quote it inside the `select`...

```
<xsl:variable name="myRegex" select="'a\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]+'"/>
```

As it is now, the processor is trying to evaluate your `select` as an XPath expression.

Also note that if you're using XSLT 1.0, you're going to have to use an [extension function](http://exslt.org/regexp/functions/match/) (and a processor that supports it).

Here's a 2.0 example...

**XML Input**

```
<doc>
    <test>a23-abcefghijk</test>
    <test>qwerty</test>
</doc>
```

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:variable name="myRegex" select="'a\d{2}-[a-zA-Z]+'"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="test">
    <test matches="{if (matches(.,$myRegex)) then 'yes' else 'no'}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </test>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<doc>
   <test matches="yes">a23-abcefghijk</test>
   <test matches="no">qwerty</test>
</doc>
```

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0 .. now I am using something like  xmlns:javaString="xalan://java.lang.String" in stylesheet 

and calling matches function

Comment: @Furqan - are you still having trouble? If so, please update your question with more details.

Comment: @Furqan - You're welcome. Also, if this answer is sufficient, please accept it by clicking on the check mark (✅) next to it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="myRegex">
  <xsl:value-of select="regExp:match('This is a test string', '(a\d{2}\-[a-zA-Z]+)', 'g'" />
</xsl:variable>
```